# rtabmap frontier exploration

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, frontier-exploration, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello community,

has somebody tried to combine RTABMAP and frontier_exploration ?
How can I solve the problem of discovering an unknown area to build a map first ?

Idea:

1. discover the area with frontier_exploration and build a map.
2. navigation in a known environment with discovered map.

Does this make sense ???

Thanks for any hints or feedback.

Cheers
Christian

ps: is google cartographer a complete solution ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260124/rtabmap-frontier-exploration/) by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 476 on 2017-04-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2017-04-24**:
Whether or not Cartographer is a complete solution depends on what problem you are trying to solve.

**Comment by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) on 2017-04-25**:
I'd like to solve the problem: lawnmower at unknown environment.
Starting always at the defined location of the base station and return after work :-)

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2017-04-25**:
For the mapping part of that problem, Cartographer will do the job. It's a very good mapping tool. Exploration will need to be handled separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

frontier_exploration claims to work with or without the `/map` topic available. RTABMAP can publish a 2D map that could be used by frontier_exploration (the [Turtlebot demo](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/MappingAndNavigationOnTurtlebot) does this). Have a look at the [frontier_exploration docs, section 2.2](http://wiki.ros.org/frontier_exploration#Exploration_with_.2BAC8-map_data), and the [Turtlebot demo for RTABMAP](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/MappingAndNavigationOnTurtlebot).

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2017-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) on 2017-04-25**:
Thanks, I will give it a try.

**Comment by [Dox](https://answers.ros.org/users/34329/dox/) on 2018-07-05**:
Hi, can you share your experience if you have tried it? Tnx.